# C# Sharepoint CSOM - Get the Display Name of a FieldValue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to display the values of a file's metadata (who created the file, time it was last updated etc) using the C# Sharepoint CSOM.

I have created a function:

```
public static void PrintFileMeta(string path)
{
        using (var context = GetContext())
        {
            File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(path);

            var item = file.ListItemAllFields;

            context.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields);

            context.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (string fieldName in item.FieldValues.Keys)
            {
                Console.Write(fieldName);
                Console.WriteLine(item.FieldValues[fieldName]);
            }

        }
}
```

However this prints the internal name of the metadata e.g. 'Created_x0020_By' instead of 'Created By' (or whatever the display name of the metadata happens to be). Is there a way to print the display name? I've been searching and testing for a while now but haven't been able to find anything that would do the trick.

Comment: you need to get fields collection and match each field with the internal name and from Field object get Title property.

Comment: Can you provide code for this? Cant figure out how to instantiate a field collection (requires object path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code.
You need to load `Fields` collection from `item.ParentList` and then search it by `InternalName`:

```
public static void PrintFileMeta(string path)
{
    using (ClientContext context = GetContext())
    {
        File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(path);

        var item = file.ListItemAllFields;
        var fields = item.ParentList.Fields;

        context.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
        context.Load(fields, include => include.Include(f => f.Id, f => f.InternalName, f => f.Title));
        context.ExecuteQuery();



        foreach (string fieldName in item.FieldValues.Keys)
        {
            Field field = fields.Where(f => f.InternalName == fieldName).First();

            Console.Write(field.Title + ": ");
            Console.WriteLine(item.FieldValues[fieldName]);
        }

    }
}
```